# USB ports work in Linux but not in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, usb

I have a few USB 2/3 ports which work great in Linux, but cannot detect anything in them on Windows.

This seems to be the problem, as shown in the Device Manager:

[image]

Any idea why these two USB buses aren't working? I've tried "deleting" them and restarting, but to no avail. Why do they work in Linux and not in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had missed one of the drivers supplied with my motherboard.

It's strange that Linux can read USB devices without a distributor driver but Windows cannot.

Comment: If your distro is released after USB 3.0 products enter the market, it's expected that the distro will support the products using available standard drivers. I suppose you're using Windows 7, which is released before USB 3.0. I've installed a new netbook with only Windows 8 standard driver and only the keyboard special buttons require additional download.

Comment: The strange thing is that I believe that the controllers were USB 2.0 controllers. Stranger still, an Intel driver was required for the rest of the USB drivers, but _only_ these few ports needed an ASRock driver. Strange.